# Pdfclown-Few different fonts of pdf files are not recognizing and also i am getting exceptions

Tags: java, pdfclown

I am facing issue with pdfclown frequently when few pdf files are non english and thier fonts are not recognizing and also i am getting below exception.Please find the [pdf path](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sy8R72jPNFUZUQxwkZoezqTZ5rpdDadU/view) and [code path](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gvZ5WjZWC073FQ2OmIf_lVUKO3N4uwoN).Load encoding method is failing in both CompositeFont.java and SimpleFont.java. And  is there any specific version of jar i need to use for to resolve this issue. Please provide your inputs for to support such  pdf files.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.CompositeFont.loadEncoding(CompositeFont.java:178)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.CompositeFont.onLoad(CompositeFont.java:202)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.load(Font.java:878)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.<init>(Font.java:368)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.CompositeFont.<init>(CompositeFont.java:114)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Type0Font.<init>(Type0Font.java:62)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.wrap(Font.java:268)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.FontResources.wrap(FontResources.java:72)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.FontResources.wrap(FontResources.java:1)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ResourceItems.get(ResourceItems.java:119)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.getResource(SetFont.java:119)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.getFont(SetFont.java:83)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.scan(SetFont.java:97)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner.moveNext(ContentScanner.java:1360)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$TextWrapper.extract(ContentScanner.java:819)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$TextWrapper.<init>(ContentScanner.java:771)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$TextWrapper.<init>(ContentScanner.java:764)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$GraphicsObjectWrapper.get(ContentScanner.java:684)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$GraphicsObjectWrapper.access$0(ContentScanner.java:676)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner.getCurrentWrapper(ContentScanner.java:1184)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:636)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:299)
    at pdfclown2.highlight(pdfclown2.java:89)
    at pdfclown2.main(pdfclown2.java:48)
```

*****************************other pdf issue*********************************************

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.SimpleFont.loadEncoding(SimpleFont.java:150)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.SimpleFont.onLoad(SimpleFont.java:170)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.load(Font.java:878)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.<init>(Font.java:368)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.SimpleFont.<init>(SimpleFont.java:65)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:47)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.wrap(Font.java:262)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.FontResources.wrap(FontResources.java:72)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.FontResources.wrap(FontResources.java:1)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ResourceItems.get(ResourceItems.java:119)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.getResource(SetFont.java:119)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.getFont(SetFont.java:83)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.scan(SetFont.java:97)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner.moveNext(ContentScanner.java:1360)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$TextWrapper.extract(ContentScanner.java:819)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$TextWrapper.<init>(ContentScanner.java:771)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$TextWrapper.<init>(ContentScanner.java:764)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$GraphicsObjectWrapper.get(ContentScanner.java:684)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$GraphicsObjectWrapper.access$0(ContentScanner.java:676)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner.getCurrentWrapper(ContentScanner.java:1184)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:636)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:645)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:299)
    at pdfclown2.highlight(pdfclown2.java:89)
    at pdfclown2.main(pdfclown2.java:48)
```

*********************************another issue**************************************

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Odd number of characters.
    at org.pdfclown.util.ConvertUtils.hexToByteArray(ConvertUtils.java:106)
    at org.pdfclown.objects.PdfString.setValue(PdfString.java:287)
    at org.pdfclown.objects.PdfString.<init>(PdfString.java:126)
    at org.pdfclown.objects.PdfByteString.<init>(PdfByteString.java:58)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.tokens.ContentParser.parsePdfObject(ContentParser.java:182)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.tokens.ContentParser.parseOperation(ContentParser.java:164)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.tokens.ContentParser.parseContentObject(ContentParser.java:98)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.tokens.ContentParser.parseContentObjects(ContentParser.java:134)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.tokens.ContentParser.parseContentObject(ContentParser.java:112)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.tokens.ContentParser.parseContentObjects(ContentParser.java:134)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.tokens.ContentParser.parseContentObject(ContentParser.java:112)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.tokens.ContentParser.parseContentObjects(ContentParser.java:134)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.tokens.ContentParser.parseContentObject(ContentParser.java:112)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.tokens.ContentParser.parseContentObjects(ContentParser.java:134)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.Contents.load(Contents.java:598)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.Contents.<init>(Contents.java:372)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.Contents.wrap(Contents.java:351)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.Page.getContents(Page.java:585)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner.<init>(ContentScanner.java:1056)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:300)
    at pdfclown2.highlight(pdfclown2.java:3124)
    at pdfclown2.main(pdfclown2.java:50)
```

Comment: I'll later look at the pdf. But yes, PDF Clown sometimes is a bit optimistic concerning the validity of pdfs from the wild. At first glance the exceptions look like errors in the pdfs ignored by most viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `NullPointerException` in `SimpleFont.loadEncoding`

I can reproduce the `NullPointerException` in `SimpleFont.loadEncoding` using your example file "Sample_Report.pdf". This is caused by an error in the PDF, some font dictionaries in there are missing required entries.

I cannot reproduce the other two exceptions using "Sample_Report.pdf", though. Thus, I'll focus on the reproducible issue.

#### The cause

In your example PDF there are some simple fonts which lack the required **FirstChar** entry, e.g.:

```
32 0 obj
<<
  /Name /EvoPdf_meeaimambhggkplibeicinfbamefiocn
  /Subtype /TrueType
  /FontDescriptor 37 0 R
  /Widths [0 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 0 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 226 326 401 498 507 715 682 221 303 303 498 498 250 306 252 386 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 507 268 268 498 498 498 463 894 579 544 533 615 488 459 631 623 252 319 520 420 855 646 662 517 673 543 459 487 642 567 890 519 487 468 307 386 307 498 498 291 479 525 423 525 498 305 471 525 230 239 455 230 799 525 527 525 525 349 391 335 525 452 715 433 453 395 314 460 314 498 507 507 507 250 305 418 690 498 498 395 1038 459 339 867 507 468 507 507 250 250 418 418 498 498 905 450 705 391 339 850 507 395 487 226 326 498 507 498 507 498 498 393 834 402 512 498 306 507 394 339 498 336 334 292 550 586 252 307 246 422 512 636 671 675 463 579 579 579 579 579 579 763 533 488 488 488 488 252 252 252 252 625 646 662 662 662 662 662 498 664 642 642 642 642 487 517 527 479 479 479 479 479 479 773 423 498 498 498 498 230 230 230 230 525 525 527 527 527 527 527 498 529 525 525 525 525 453 525 453 ]
  /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
  /Type /Font
  /BaseFont /Calibri
  /LastChar 255 >>
endobj
```

According to the PDF specification ISO 32000-1 (and similarly ISO 32000-2, too), **TrueType** font dictionaries contain the same entries as **Type1** font dictionaries (with certain differences irrelevant to the case at hand), and the section on **Type1** fonts specifies:

> **FirstChar**
> integer
> *(Required except for the standard 14 fonts)* The first character code defined in the font’s Widths array.

The font above is not a standard 14 font. Thus, it is required to have a **FirstChar** entry. It does not. Thus, this font definition is broken.

PDF Clown, on the other hand, expects PDFs to follow the specification. So it simply retrieves the **FirstChar** value from the font and immediately uses it which results in the `NullPointerException`.

#### A work-around

One can make PDF Clown a bit more lax by making it default to 0 in its `SimpleFont` **FirstChar** lookups. There are two such lookups.

In `SimpleFont.loadEncoding()` replace

```java
ByteArray charCode = new ByteArray(new byte[]{(byte)((PdfInteger)getBaseDataObject().get(PdfName.FirstChar)).getIntValue()});
```

by

```java
PdfInteger firstCharObject = (PdfInteger)getBaseDataObject().get(PdfName.FirstChar);
ByteArray charCode = new ByteArray(new byte[]{(byte)(firstCharObject != null ? firstCharObject.getIntValue() : 0)});
```

and in `SimpleFont.onLoad()` similarly replace

```java
ByteArray charCode = new ByteArray(
    new byte[]
        {(byte)((PdfInteger)getBaseDataObject().get(PdfName.FirstChar)).getIntValue()}
);
```

by

```java
PdfInteger firstCharObject = (PdfInteger)getBaseDataObject().get(PdfName.FirstChar);
ByteArray charCode = new ByteArray(
    new byte[]
        {(byte)(firstCharObject != null ? firstCharObject.getIntValue() : 0)}
);
```

as it already has been done [here](https://github.com/mkl-public/pdfclown/blob/develop/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/fonts/SimpleFont.java).

### `NullPointerException` in `CompositeFont.loadEncoding`

I can reproduce the `NullPointerException` in `CompositeFont.loadEncoding` using your example file "UnicodeTest.pdf". These exceptions are caused by missing encoding CMaps in PDF Clown.

There is a number of **Encodings** primarily for CJK languages which a conforming PDF processor is expected to support but which PDF libraries (in particular those developed in Europe or the Americas) often don't support out of the box.

PDF Clown expects such encoding CMaps as resources in /fonts/cmap/ in the pdfclown.jar; by default, though, only the generic CMaps **Identity-H** and **Identity-V** are there, and none of the specific Chinese/Japanese/Korean CMaps.

You can add the required CMaps to the pdfclown.jar by adding them to the `main\res\pkg\fonts\cmap\` folder of the PDF Clown project and building the jar file.

You can retrieve all CMaps from the [adobe-type-tools/cmap-resources](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/cmap-resources) project on github, simply traverse the folder structure of that project and collect the files from the `CMap` subfolders.

In case of your example file the CMaps **UniCNS-UTF16-H**, **UniGB-UTF16-H**, **UniJIS-UTF16-H**, and **UniKS-UTF16-H** sufficed but for an application working with arbitrary PDF files you probably should add all encoding CMaps.

Comment: Is there any specific version of jar i need to import for resolving all the issues.Due to security concerns i can't share my pdf documents for 1st and 3rd issue.There so many docs are failing as first scenario.

Comment: @Seshadri *"Is there any specific version of jar i need to import for resolving all the issues."* - No. The stack traces of the problems suggest that those documents are broken, and as you cannot share sample documents, I cannot analyze them to probably find some PDF Clown problem. PDF viewers usually are very lax but programs/libraries without GUI need to be more strict because they don't have the user in front who can stop the process as he recognizes something goes wrong. Thus, to resolve the issue you have to request fixed versions of those documents.

Comment: In my pdf document different types of fonts are there like the  screen shot which i shared and let me know whether this information is enough to reproduce this issue .  [pdf fonts and types](https://drive.google.com/open?id=163eh2WnNp7NS4bthn2hjnryUHhpCZqpQ)

Comment: *"whether this information is enough to reproduce this issue"* - It is not. Those fonts tab outputs can be created both for correctly and for in different ways incorrectly created and/or used font objects in a PDF.

Comment: @Seshadri Are you still going to share representative example PDFs giving rise to the other exceptions? If you don't, please accept this answer.

Comment: please find the document for following issue [pdf path](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Rwdn9j4XciQDeQ23_4jSgy5xjG6R__S/view)   at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.CompositeFont.loadEncoding(CompositeFont.java:178).Please provide your inputs .Thanks in advance.

Comment: With that file I could reproduce the issue. I explained the cause and the solution in my answer, see the new section "`NullPointerException` in `CompositeFont.loadEncoding`"...

Comment: @mkl-Thanks for your support.Now following  issue "NullPointerException in CompositeFont.loadEncoding" has been resolved.And still only one issue  is pending.i.e(java.lang.RuntimeException: Odd number of characters.at org.pdfclown.util. ConvertUtils. hexToByteArray (ConvertUtils.java:106)).Please provide inputs for that issue.

Comment: The problem with the pending issue is that there is no natural way to correct it. It is about hex-encoded byte sequences. A byte naturally requires two hex-digits, from 00 to FF, but in your PDF such a hex-encoded byte sequence has an odd number of digits; what should we assume to be the intended sequence? E.g. consider `89ABC`, should this be `08 9A BC`? Or `89 AB C0`? Or even `89 AB 0C`? Or should we simply drop the extra nibble resulting in `89 AB` here?